# How to merge my own duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, specific-question, duplicate

How to merge my own duplicate question?

Such as:

[When a package recommends A or B, which one is installed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364481/when-a-package-recommends-a-or-b-which-one-is-installed)

[Why isn't lxterminal installed when installing lxde-core?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363357/why-isnt-lxterminal-installed-when-installing-lxde-core?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 4):

Since the question has already been marked as a duplicate, you can simply click on the button to accept the dupe target:

[image: accept dupe button]

For more information on this feature, see:
[New UI encourages askers to confirm or dispute duplicate votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250981/203101)

Comment: That is duplicate due my mistake(I not sure which one is best version of same question) , but still no any really useful answer,so now I want only merge that two question.

Comment: @illiterate what do you mean "merge"? One is already closed. If any information from that one is missing from the other one, edit it and add the missing information.

Comment: @illiterate I cast the first duplication vote. I chose to mark the older as the duplicate of the newer question since the newer question had an upvoted answer but the older had none.